# 2016 US national election exit poll data

Tags: data-request, usa, elections

I'm looking for 2016 US national election exit poll data. Is there an open source version of these data?

Essentially, I'd like access to the NYTimes data shown here:
http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2016/11/08/us/politics/election-exit-polls.html

NYTimes characterizes their data:

> The voter survey is based on questionnaires completed by 24,537 voters leaving 350 voting places throughout the United States on Election Day including 4,398 telephone interviews with early and absentee voters.

The source is cited as:

> Edison Research for the National Election Pool, a consortium of ABC News, The Associated Press, CBSNews, CNN, Fox News and NBC News.

Is there an open version of these (or similar) 2016 exit poll data?

Note: there is an ongoing study that computes *"exit poll" style results* using ecological influence ([Flaxman et al., 2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.03787)), but I'm seeking actual exit polls.

Answer (score 3):

I found a source of [2016 Exit Poll data](https://data.world/mrapple/2016-exit-polling-data) from data.world (requires registration)

> Exit-polling data is typically considered as the most informative data source for revealing the election day process, as it is well studied and used for announcing presidential election prediction. Another interesting aspect of the exit-polling data is that the statistics based on the questionair reflects the state-level public opinions on certain topics, which could be used as state-level public sentiment features or proxies for future analyses and modeling. It also could give great insights for future campaingn strategies. Thus, it is of great values to collect and analyze the Exit-Polling data.
>
> Preliminary Analysis: [Scrape and Analyze Exit-Polling Data](https://github.com/Data4Democracy/election-transparency/blob/master/notebooks/r-notebooks/collect_exit_polling_data.Rmd) (with R source code)
>
> Data Source: [CNN](http://www.cnn.com/election/results/exit-polls/national/president)

Here's a sample of how the CSV looks. It's not "raw-raw" data, but aggregated to each state and demographic category.

[image]